# error TS2339: Property 'catch' does not exist on type 'PromiseLike<void>'

Tags: angular, typescript, promise, getusermedia, typescript2.0

I am using WebRTC in Angular 2.

In **TypeScript 1.x**, I can use this successfully.

```
   navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints)
      .then(myStream => {
        this.myStream = myStream;
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
```

But after updating to **TypeScript 2.x**, I got this error in my terminal when I run `npm run watch`:

> error TS2339: Property 'catch' does not exist on type
>   'PromiseLike'.

My IDE WebStore shows red too:

[image]

I already did `npm install --save-dev @types/webrtc`.

My **tsconfig.json** file:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "removeComments": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "lib": ["es6", "dom"],
    "types": [
      "body-parser",
      "compression",
      "express",
      "express-session",
      "mime",
      "node",
      "serve-static",
      "webrtc",
      "ws"
    ]
  },
  "include": [
    "node_modules/@types/**/*.d.ts",
    "src/**/*.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "!node_modules/@types/**/*.d.ts"
  ],
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "buildOnSave": false,
  "atom": {
    "rewriteTsconfig": false
  }
}
```

I am using [universal-starter](https://github.com/angular/universal-starter) as start, so my **nodemon.json** and **package.json** are same with them, just has more packages.

How can I get rid of that error?

Comment: What does `getUserMedia` return?

Comment: @torazaburo it returns `Promise<MediaStream>`

Comment: @HongboMiao Please post the full error message (with call stack). I cann't reproduce this error if I run your example. `getUserMedia.then` returns a `Promise` and not a `PromiseLike` in my setup. Thereby, I don't get an error. Does this error appear at a different location in your "real code" or do you get this error with this exact code?

Comment: @HongboMiao Please post your *tsconfig.json*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The build-in library `dom` declares the issue causing definition (see [lib.dom.d.ts](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.dom.d.ts#L8277)):

```
getUserMedia(constraints: MediaStreamConstraints): PromiseLike<MediaStream>;
```

whereas `@types/webrtc` declares your expected definition (see [MediaStream.d.ts](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/types-2.0/webrtc/MediaStream.d.ts#L105)):

```
getUserMedia(constraints: MediaStreamConstraints): Promise<MediaStream>;
```

There is an [open issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10242) in the TypeScript repository.

Comment: Oh, I were happy too early. after change to `"lib": ["es6", "dom", "es2015.promise"],` still shows same error in the terminal when I run `npm run watch`

Comment: `"es6"` includes `"es2015.promise"`. Thus, you don't need `"es2015.promise"`

Comment: How does your `watch` script in your `package.json` look like?

Comment: I added more details in my question. Since I am using universal-starter, so the `watch` script is like [this line](https://github.com/angular/universal-starter/blob/master/package.json#L10). (Note that my IDE WebStorm also shows red for `catch`)

Comment: Now I am guessing it is a bug of @types/webrtc, because when I use promise with catch on other like mongoose, it won't give me any error.

Comment: Its caused by TypeScript's dom library (see my updated answer).